# Why doesnt Bootstraps panel collapse work with JSF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, xhtml

Here is the code for my panel:

```
<div class="panel-group destinfo" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    <h3><b>OVERVIEW</b></h3>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <p>Some text here</p>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

When I click the panel, it doesnt open up the whole panel with `<p>some text here</p>`. It did that when I tried it in notepad++, but in netbeans(maven web application + JSF Framework) it doesnt work. What is wrong here?

Comment: You should load jQuery first, does that fix it?

Comment: As David mentioned.. Move the bootstrap.min.js under the jquery code.. It should work.

Comment: It works fine now! Thanks @DavidG Write a answer to my question so I can accept it&upvote!

Comment: How did you miss the `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` message in the JavaScript error console??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Bootstrap, you need to load jQuery before the Bootstrap libraries, like this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```